# Email getting directed to wrong user (Postfix / Dovecot)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I'm having issues with some emails getting put in the wrong mailbox. I'm not sure if it's a postfix or dovecot issue. It only occurs infrequently. Below the email should have gone to sue@domain.com, but instead went to r@domain.com. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Return-Path: <officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>
X-Original-To: r@domain.com
Delivered-To: r@domain.com
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 61C459A0F0A
    for <r@domain.com>; Sat, 17 Oct 2020 10:22:32 +1100 (AEDT)
Authentication-Results: mail.domain.com;
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=comms.officeworks.com.au header.i=@comms.officeworks.com.au header.a=rsa-sha256 header.s=neolane header.b=bmjCqzUB;
    dkim-atps=neutral
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at domain.com
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Score: -0.197
X-Spam-Level:
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.197 tagged_above=-9999 required=5
    tests=[DKIMWL_WL_HIGH=-1, DKIM_SIGNED=0.1, DKIM_VALID=-0.1,
    DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1, HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST=0.001,
    HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_04=0.001, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001,
    RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE=-0.0001, RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H3=-0.01,
    RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_WL=-0.01, SPF_FAIL=0.919, SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001]
    autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Received: from mail.domain.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (mail.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id oHbmV4izVrd4 for <r@domain.com>;
    Sat, 17 Oct 2020 10:22:26 +1100 (AEDT)
Received: from mail-pf1-f199.google.com (mail-pf1-f199.google.com [209.85.210.199])
    by mail.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 623519A0F08
    for <r@domain.com>; Sat, 17 Oct 2020 10:22:22 +1100 (AEDT)
Received: by mail-pf1-f199.google.com with SMTP id n85so2254501pfd.6
        for <r@domain.com>; Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:22:22 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:dkim-signature:from:subject:date:to:reply-to
         :mime-version:message-id:list-unsubscribe:delivered-to;
        bh=Quoqx1uSMwOGt1TeX/BNOeCiRXJ43INDQy81QOSyIEQ=;
        b=EmFjUTF0msQtyYdr7g8tgDqYTlQjtCwsL9rTliQ7xaxQrzMlae8o0r3rhqlh2fgNrt
         Vzo05ld1l0iuMIIB5B4mqJOrVQir5Nrba8eNBq7pSv1JmFI5TcC0F39YdTAXWm94UtE+
         2bxaMEoNzKE65c2pga9zINZ5Dza3nFlEzHeue4SCOI0TRgwwMNwlkZ+VVLyNuoigx751
         slNVKa2sOCyldTNSoImPT+mzpbdHQqRezfPXh/HolFaMbtQfkqpXggQ5M1DLT15CB33b
         JL7VIkOTgZey9UBlGaU56VMPkEACs7ql6OrCLPzDrqbX44Zj+7ne9CB6dIVOIpS+Oh3f
         nExg==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOAM531VmbUqJmqTjXHOFOMsaRyp+xMZiytyHDXS5n61ia7nm++FeX2y
    k+Dwij0V8eQdkxi3CBnLQXDkIY5jve5Bv5Y+q+CgPXrTDcmb5mr2NOXGIk1/sfRcRl3eQ8m6NrX
    Dm3JJwQ7u/d0+QXXckRrbfn5YpdB/
X-Received: by 2002:a17:902:a407:b029:d2:2113:7f8f with SMTP id p7-20020a170902a407b02900d221137f8fmr6468415plq.70.1602890540364;
        Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:22:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJwa0wUG94ReyN91E90antHxCBsL6SbKcDtyISM99iBoZqidu31DCmM6uMZml6Q/N7Hpf67A
X-Received: by 2002:a17:902:a407:b029:d2:2113:7f8f with SMTP id p7-20020a170902a407b02900d221137f8fmr6468382plq.70.1602890539788;
        Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:22:19 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1602890539; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=uYlKN9yPZLkSRDHHgcGA8yvocKCbGWvqtjqHqt2i3x4ugYYyW5kOyy3JwE6Zkh6ixk
         Hkktuw417EEO2uTfcfbkhoGJjUkf8gY61jNV54PfeHzkTNmH+MsHyODjMDp/yrjGwlHx
         g9q3dwn0/4QoHErhOvme0H8oDxg+hHqFJS5Qrh5enug8y7g5r71A8EaJ5o8OAEqeWX82
         3w31JDIo0jA2JJ9WqcPFS73+tb0Ek43IVLAohmnGIsUqkXj5ZjcZ+xJoECncd/r3IguA
         BSiLNkp35tco5ADgduutGGNMxggnlr/nFOFt96sHF1bAc35FOYebxP2Z6zOgBC5IMTZG
         mIjQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=list-unsubscribe:message-id:mime-version:reply-to:to:date:subject
         :from:dkim-signature;
        bh=Quoqx1uSMwOGt1TeX/BNOeCiRXJ43INDQy81QOSyIEQ=;
        b=A7q4kFvR6kr8zJe5qEEM62y8wQ+L+vXUHwgFB7FWJUIrQFGOL3/RV0Dv8nPbApqaTZ
         Z7tgeyKPi5mGXJB4iMluKZsX5W3NuhLoOkxPNpq3dYZiGxxTNW9C1H12xaaZUGJsosla
         f6W9PMeqWhlxmzrMTZH6tKKMtklAgXURFw0cv+6AAtIRYdz1wTphpK9Gc7rPTID5YMPY
         rcCgC3/JwTWRnxuaegleIkobSNpKzTU6LQ1a7gqMMYSbC7gG3zo5EasInStxtMiAge7o
         lF626WyL9Ws1nlCpg5xAB0LofokAw4coJvqNdycBz4oNaNy3rerG2MMvZ12qGgkXFNZl
         xKTw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@comms.officeworks.com.au header.s=neolane header.b=bmjCqzUB;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au designates 63.140.47.175 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=comms.officeworks.com.au
Received: from r175.p47.neolane.net (r175.p47.neolane.net. [63.140.47.175])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id d9si3555580pgg.124.2020.10.16.16.22.19
        for <sue@domain.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:22:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au designates 63.140.47.175 as permitted sender) client-ip=63.140.47.175;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@comms.officeworks.com.au header.s=neolane header.b=bmjCqzUB;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au designates 63.140.47.175 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=comms.officeworks.com.au
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=comms.officeworks.com.au; s=neolane; t=1602890544;
    bh=Quoqx1uSMwOGt1TeX/BNOeCiRXJ43INDQy81QOSyIEQ=;
    h=From:Subject:Date:To:MIME-Version:Message-ID:List-Unsubscribe:
     Content-Type;
    b=bmjCqzUB+/Yd/OYr4iOteQsqFDx2Z8uJHee86Z5zQlCxXXWwXcU7SZ6Jl51u2FI/I
     RPK0mVnoBQyQ4HtfGtBbgZJlch+UZAwJWxIpHgU418+oCGabn8CrI2cslC/c5NZnfD
     gjMPqSHS0dW58A/dPkBJztKlvnfxYjgSTqEVBPLc=
Received: from [52.76.154.61] ([52.76.154.61:2685] helo=r175.p47.neolane.net)
    by momentum08.sin2.cpt.adobe.net (envelope-from <officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>)
    (ecelerity 4.2.31.59853 r(Core:4.2.31.1)) with ESMTP
    id CC/83-03595-F2B2A8F5; Fri, 16 Oct 2020 16:22:24 -0700
From: "Officeworks" <email@comms.officeworks.com.au>
Subject: Introducing iPhone 12
Date: Sat, 17 Oct 2020 07:22:15 +0800
To: <sue@domain.com>
Reply-To: "Officeworks" <officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-mailer: nlserver, Build 6.7.0
Message-ID: <NM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au?subject=unsubscribe%3CNM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au%3E>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_214_BC7C0828.BC7C0828"
Delivered-To: sue@domain.com

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_214_BC7C0828.BC7C0828
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Mail Log:

```
Oct 17 10:22:21 mail postfix/smtpd[38937]: connect from mail-pf1-f199.google.com[209.85.210.199]
Oct 17 10:22:22 mail postfix/smtpd[38937]: 623519A0F08: client=mail-pf1-f199.google.com[209.85.210.199]
Oct 17 10:22:22 mail postfix/cleanup[38941]: 623519A0F08: message-id=<NM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>
Oct 17 10:22:26 mail opendkim[1306]: 623519A0F08: s=neolane d=comms.officeworks.com.au a=rsa-sha256 SSL
Oct 17 10:22:26 mail postfix/qmgr[26101]: 623519A0F08: from=<officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>, size=66404, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 17 10:22:26 mail postfix/smtpd[38937]: disconnect from mail-pf1-f199.google.com[209.85.210.199] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 bdat=2 quit=1 commands=8
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/smtpd[38946]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/smtpd[38946]: 61C459A0F0A: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/cleanup[38941]: 61C459A0F0A: message-id=<NM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail opendkim[1306]: 61C459A0F0A: s=neolane d=comms.officeworks.com.au a=rsa-sha256 SSL
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/smtpd[38946]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/qmgr[26101]: 61C459A0F0A: from=<officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>, size=67391, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail amavis[38334]: (38334-08) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInbound}, [209.85.210.199]:39886 [52.76.154.61] <officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au> -> <r@domain.com>, Queue-ID: 623519A0F08, Message-ID: <NM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>, mail_id: oHbmV4izVrd4, Hits: -0.197, size: 66574, queued_as: 61C459A0F0A, dkim_sd=neolane:comms.officeworks.com.au, 6238 ms
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/smtp[38942]: 623519A0F08: to=<r@domain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=10, delays=3.8/0.02/0/6.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 61C459A0F0A)
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/qmgr[26101]: 623519A0F08: removed
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail dovecot: lda(r)<38949><HJhpGzgril8lmAAAZU03Dg>: sieve: msgid=<NM6BDD0900D92FF2AB5officeworks@comms.officeworks.com.au>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/local[38947]: 61C459A0F0A: to=<r@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /etc/postfix/dovecot-lda-relay -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT")
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail postfix/qmgr[26101]: 61C459A0F0A: removed
Oct 17 10:22:32 mail dovecot: indexer-worker(r)<38951><HJhpGzgril8lmAAAZU03Dg:Mo5THTgril8nmAAAZU03Dg>: Indexed 1 messages in INBOX (UIDs 762..762)
```

I'm trialling adding this to main.cf of postfix config:

```
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
```

Comment: Check the mail server logs.

Comment: Observation: The above mail switches from `for <sue@domain.com>` to `for <r@domain.com>` in two `Received` headers both by `by *.google.com` separated by ARC seals.

Comment: The change of recipient appears to have happened at Google, not at your mail server. It's not clear why this message was sent via Google at all.